# Host should be a string error in ansible

Tags: vmware, ansible

This is the error I get when I run this code.

```
[my-host]
 19.3.112.97  ansible_ssh_pass=mypass ansible_ssh_user=root
```

The play book is

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  tasks:
    - vsphere_guest:
        guest: newvm001
        vmware_guest_facts: yes
```

Error:

> An exception occurred during task execution. The full traceback is:
>   Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/var/folders/zt/s5ykx9_n4y9611h_k_gj_vx00000gn/T/ansible_vYePRK/ansible_module_vsphere_guest.py",
>   line 1879, in 
>       main()   File "/var/folders/zt/s5ykx9_n4y9611h_k_gj_vx00000gn/T/ansible_vYePRK/ansible_module_vsphere_guest.py",
>   line 1748, in main
>       viserver.connect(vcenter_hostname, username, password)   File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pysphere/vi_server.py", line 71, in
>   connect
>       ,FaultTypes.PARAMETER_ERROR) pysphere.resources.vi_exception.VIException: [Parameter Error]: 'host'
>   should be a string with the ESX/VC url.
>
> fatal: [9.1.142.86]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "failed": true,
>   "invocation": {"module_name": "vsphere_guest"}, "module_stderr":
>   "Traceback (most recent call last):\n  File
>   \"/var/folders/zt/s5ykx9_n4y9611h_k_gj_vx00000gn/T/ansible_vYePRK/ansible_module_vsphere_guest.py\",
>   line 1879, in \n    main()\n  File
>   \"/var/folders/zt/s5ykx9_n4y9611h_k_gj_vx00000gn/T/ansible_vYePRK/ansible_module_vsphere_guest.py\",
>   line 1748, in main\n    viserver.connect(vcenter_hostname, username,
>   password)\n  File
>   \"/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pysphere/vi_server.py\", line 71,
>   in connect\n
>   ,FaultTypes.PARAMETER_ERROR)\npysphere.resources.vi_exception.VIException:
>   [Parameter Error]: 'host' should be a string with the ESX/VC url.\n",
>   "module_stdout": "", "msg": "MODULE FAILURE", "parsed": false}

Why do i get this error?

Comment: This is what, your eighth question on the same section of code? And you haven't accepted an answer out asked for clarification?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are currently supplying two parameters to `vsphere_guest`, `guest` and `vmware_guest_facts`.  However, [the documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/vsphere_guest_module.html) lists several more parameters as being required:

- password
- username
- vcenter_hostname

If I had to guess, `vcenter_hostname` is defaulting to `None` (Python's null equivalent) and so the code that expects it to be a URI string throws the exception you see there.